# Combine two nested IF statements with multiple criteria

Tags: if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have two columns of data in "Meds" sheet...

```
  MedContinuing     AgeAtMedStop
      Yes             "Blank"
      Yes              72.22
      No              "Blank"
      No               72.57
    "Blank"            73.85
```

I am writing a formula in a separate sheet to return 1 or 0 based on the following:

1. If `MedContinuing` is "Blank", do nothing
2. If `MedContinuing` is "No" and `AgeAtMedStop` is blank, do nothing
3. If `MedContinuing` is "Yes" and `AgeAtMedStop` is "Blank", return 1. If `AgeAtMedStop` is a number, return 0.
4. If `MedContinuing` is "No" and `AgeAtMedStop` is a number, return 1. Otherwise, return nothing.

I was able to write two separate functions (see below) for when `MedContinuing` is "Yes" or when it is "No", but I need to combine both into one formula.

When it's Yes...

```
=IF(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="","",
IF(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="No","",
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="Yes",INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))=""),1,0)))
```

When it's No...

```
=IF(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="","",
IF(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="Yes","",
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="No",INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))=""),"",
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="No",INDEX(Meds!2:2,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))>0),1,0))))
```

**EDIT: Solution**

Using Peter K's logic...

```
=IF(INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="","",
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="No",INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))=""),"",
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="Yes",INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))=""),1,
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="Yes",INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))>0),0,
IF(AND(INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("MedContinuing",Meds!$1:$1,0))="No",INDEX(Meds!6:6,MATCH("AgeAtMedStop",Meds!$1:$1,0))>0),1,"")))))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear from your question why you would use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions for such straightforward problem ?

I suggest to start with the basic nested if function :
`=IF(A2="";"";IF(A2="No";IF(B2="";"";1);IF(B2="";1;0)))`

You can put this function next to your two columns, and then copy to another worksheet, so the references are taken care of by Excel.
I also assume that your data is clean and correct i.e. only the 3 possible values for MedContinuing ("Yes", "No" or blank) and 2 for AgeAtMedStop (blank or a number) exist in your columns, so no `IF` test is needed to eliminate other possible values.

Comment: thanks but your formula didn't work. Even after I replaced the semicolons with commas. However, I was able to edit your formula and get it working. `=IF(A2="","",IF(AND(A2="No",B2=""),"",IF(AND(A2="Yes",B2=""),1,IF(AND(A2="Yes",ISNUMBER(B2)),0,IF(AND(A2="No",ISNUMBER(B2)),1,"")))))`. The reason I have INDEX-MATCH is too long to explain, but it's required. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to incorporate your basic logic with my solution for the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks. I shortened the IFs because of the assumptions I mentioned in my answer, but your formula is of course more exhaustive and will also work if other values are present in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method below

I have created a helper table for the logic you require, it will help to update or extend the logic in future

Formula in cell C2 is

```
=INDEX($F$2:$G$4,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$4,0),IF(B2="Blank",1,IF(ISNUMBER(B2),2,0)))
```

[image]